# Compactness and spanning relationship

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am working from Brin and Stuck's textbook on Dynamical Systems. They quote the following: By compactness, there are finite (n,ϵ)-spanning sets. Can anybody explain why this is the case? I can sort of see that because of finite subcovers, the set must be finite, but why must there exist a spanning set in the first place?

They define (n,ϵ)-spanning sets as follows:

> A subset A⊂ X is $(n, \epsilon)$-spanning if for every x ∈ X there is
>   y ∈ A such that $d_n(x, y) < \epsilon$.

They define compactness by covers. For further context, see the following link to the passage I am working from (found online): http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jswlamb/m3a23/TopEntropyfromBS.pdf

Note: I asked a similar question previously, but cannot access to my account to update it.

Comment: For your original cover, take the set of all $\epsilon$-balls centred on every point in the space. Trivially, every point in the space belongs to one such ball.